# golang how to print struct value with pointer

Tags: pointers, go, struct, printing

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    a int32
    B *B
}
type B struct {
    b int32
}

func main() {
    a := &A{
        a: 1,
        B: &B{
            b: 2,
        },
    }
    fmt.Printf("v ==== %+v \n", a)
}


//ret: v ==== &{a:1 B:0xc42000e204}
//??? how to print B's content but not pointer
```

Comment: By the way. It's bad form on this site (and others) to just paste nothing but code in the question. (by the way @JimB how were you able to edit the question while still having it be only code? It wouldn't let me edit it. Is it a privilege from your rep?)

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 17):

Basically, you have to do it yourself. There are two ways to do this. Either just print the thing how you want, or implement the `Stringer` interface for the struct by adding a `func String() string`, which gets called when you use the format `%v`. You could also reference each value in the format which is a struct.

Implementing the `Stringer` interface is the surest way to always get what you want. And you only have to do it once per struct, instead of per format string when you print.

https://play.golang.org/p/PKLcPFCqOe

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    a int32
    B *B
}

type B struct{ b int32 }

func (aa *A) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("A{a:%d, B:%v}",aa.a,aa.B)
}

func (bb *B) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("B{b:%d}",bb.b)
}

func main() {
    a := &A{a: 1, B: &B{b: 2}}

    // using the Stringer interface
    fmt.Printf("v ==== %v \n", a)

    // or just print it yourself however you want.
    fmt.Printf("v ==== A{a:%d, B:B{b:%d}}\n", a.a, a.B.b)

    // or just reference the values in the struct that are structs themselves
    // but this can get really deep
    fmt.Printf("v ==== A{a:%d, B:%v}", a.a, a.B)
}
```

Comment: Note that the second option will panic in case `B` is `nil` while first and third will print nicely `<nil>`

Comment: @ain just another reason why the `Stringer` implementation is superior.

Answer (score 11):

When you get into larger structs, it becomes a pain to write a bunch of custom String functions. Goconvey currently uses the following project to show diffs and expected/actual output on structs of any size: https://github.com/luci/go-render/blob/master/render/render.go#L51. It includes displaying pointer values.

If you need the output to be re-usable as code (like `fmt.Printf("%#v", a)` but include pointer values), I have a forked version of the above project which will render full nested pointers as re-usable code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gdexlab/go-render/render"
)

type A struct {
    a int32
    B *B
}
type B struct {
    b int32
}

func main() {
    a := &A{
        a: 1,
        B: &B{
            b: 2,
        },
    }
    output := render.AsCode(a)
    fmt.Println(output)

}
// outputs: "&A{a:1, B:&B{b:2}}" compared to initial version of "&{a:1 B:0xc42000e204}"
```

Go Playground Example:
https://play.golang.org/p/tcfJYb0NnVf

Answer (score 10):

Another simple solution is to print the struct using marshaling. This works only for exported (public) variables by capitalizing the first char inside the struct.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "encoding/json"
)

type A struct {
    Aa int32
    B *B
}
type B struct {
    Bb int32
}
func main() {
    a := &A{
        Aa: 1,
        B: &B{
            Bb: 2,
        },
    }
    aJSON, _ := json.Marshal(a)
    fmt.Printf("JSON Print - \n%s\n", string(aJSON))


    aYAML, _ := yaml.Marshal(a)
    fmt.Printf("YAML Print - \n%s\n", string(aYAML))
}
```

Output :-

```
JSON Print - 
{"Aa":1,"B":{"Bb":2}}
YAML Print - 
aa: 1
b:
  bb: 2
```

If you are printing the struct multiple times then implement Stringer interface as follows :-

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type A struct {
    Aa int32
    B *B
}

func (a A) String() string {
    bytes, _ := yaml.Marshal(a)
    return string(bytes)
}

type B struct {
    Bb int32
}

func main() {
    a := &A{
        Aa: 1,
        B: &B{
            Bb: 2,
        },
    }

    fmt.Printf("YAML Print - \n%+v\n", a)
}
```

Output -

```
YAML Print - 
aa: 1
b:
  bb: 2
```

Comment: This is a far simpler solution for a beginner like me .. Thanks a bunch !!!

Comment: This freaking fantastic. Thank you very nice and easy find for when debugging

Answer (score 3):

Use fmt and reflect.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type A struct {
    a int32
    B *B
}
type B struct {
    b int32
}

func main() {
    a := &A{
        a: 1,
        B: &B{
            b: 2,
        },
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", GetGoString(a)) // output: &A{a: 1, B: &B{b: 2}}
}

func GetGoString(v interface{}) string {
    return getGoString(reflect.ValueOf(v))
}

func getGoString(v reflect.Value) string {
    switch v.Kind() {
    case reflect.Invalid:
        return "nil"
    case reflect.Struct:
        t := v.Type()
        out := getTypeString(t) + "{"
        for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
            if i > 0 {
                out += ", "
            }
            fieldValue := v.Field(i)
            field := t.Field(i)
            out += fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s", field.Name, getGoString(fieldValue))
        }
        out += "}"
        return out
    case reflect.Interface, reflect.Ptr:
        if v.IsZero() {
            return fmt.Sprintf("(%s)(nil)", getTypeString(v.Type()))
        }
        return "&" + getGoString(v.Elem())
    case reflect.Slice:
        out := getTypeString(v.Type())
        if v.IsZero() {
            out += "(nil)"
        } else {
            out += "{"
            for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
                if i > 0 {
                    out += ", "
                }
                out += getGoString(v.Index(i))
            }
            out += "}"
        }
        return out
    default:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%#v", v)
    }
}

func getTypeString(t reflect.Type) string {
    if t.PkgPath() == "main" {
        return t.Name()
    }
    return t.String()
}
```

Comment: There is also a lack of assertions about maps: `case reflect.Map`

Answer (score 2):

### Implement `Stringer` interface to custom `type`

- no external packages
- no need to wrap types in other types

example:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    B *B `json:"b"`
}

type B int

func (b *B) String() string {
    if b == nil {
        return "nil"
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("%d", *b)
}

func main() {
    var a A
    fmt.Printf("a: %+v\n", a)
    a.B = B(3)
    fmt.Printf("a: %+v\n", a)
}
```

output:

```bash
a: {B:nil}
a: {B:3}
```